# Conditional sum with merged cells using Sumiif()

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario is 2 worksheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Sheet1 config:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2 Config:

[image: Sheet2]

The problem:
The customer wants to input the daily amounts of bananas in Sheet2 (C:C) and have the totals automatically add in Sheet1 for the week number. The problem I'm facing with this, I believe is the merged cells. I was successful when I removed the merged cells and added the week number to all the cells with this formula    ( =SUMIF(A:A,E3,'Sheet2!C:C) ) But the customer would prefer to keep the merged cells, and with that it only returns the first value of that week. Am I missing something simple here? Can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merged cells are a bad idea for several reasons and should be avoided.

That does not mean that you can't achieve the look your client wants. You can fill the numbers into all the unmerged cells and then use conditional formatting to hide six of the seven numbers. In the screenshot below, column A has a conditional format with this formula

```
=MOD((ROW()+2)/7,1)
```

The format applied is custom number format `;;;` (or use white font on white background). Adjust the formula if your data starts on a different row.

Note that the formula bar clearly shows that the selected cell has the value 26.

[image]

Comment: Amazing solution! Compared to [the first solution by @ScottCraner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031885/excel-weekly-sums-with-grouped-cells#34032210), the OP would be able to use a regular `SUMIF` on the whole column and not to loose performance, as array formulas work bad if they are applied to the whole column. I was thinking about some UDF, but this would easily work in a macro-disabled file and I see it as an advantage.

Comment: @ZygD Ta. Yes, avoid merged cells, so you can use regular formulas that reference each row or column. That is one of the reasons to avoid merged cells. The formatting  is just the icing on the cake. Experienced Excel bakers have that in their toolbox.

Comment: <Sarcasm> I worked very hard for my formula and here you come and give a simple fix. mumble..mumble..</Sarcasm>  This works great in this instance, but what if the spacing was not identical but varied?  Could your approach be modified for this?  I am not trying to be difficult just curious, because I run into this often.  I agree it should be avoided but I have bosses that like the look.

Comment: @ScottCraner If there are irregular numbers of rows in each set, a conditional format can be set up for a change in value. If the value in the row above is different, then show this cell's value.

Comment: Hey my apologizes for the delayed thank you! But this answer turned out to work great for this scenario, definitively what I was looking for. I appreciate the help, thanks a bunch! Keep up the awesome work miss!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found:

```
=SUM(IF(LOOKUP(ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$15),ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$15)/(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$15<>""),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$15)=A2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$15))
```

This is an array formula.  Enter into sheet 1 C2.  Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Then copy down.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the important aspect to this specific layout is that a week has 7 days and you are listing every day in the week. A merged cell is identified by the top-left cell in the merged area. Looking for 26 returns A2 and looking for 27 returns A9. If you reference column C with those row numbers and extend the range to 7 rows then you can sum for the matching week.

In G2 (per the image supplied),

```
'volatile OFFSET function
=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(C:C, MATCH(E2, A:A, 0)), 0, 0, 7, 1))
'non-volatile INDEX function
=SUM(INDEX(C:C, MATCH(E2, A:A, 0)):INDEX(C:C, MATCH(E2, A:A, 0)+6))
```

The dates in either table are inconsequential beyond visual reference.

[image]

Comment: works fine in this case, but does not in the general case where for example week 28 becomes week 26 again in column A...